# Returning all paths from a given source to a destination rather than printing them

Tags: python, graph

I have been working in python with this ['routes and paths' code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/). This code works fine; however, my question is about how can I extract the results like a variable - using return - rather than printing it.

Comment: You can’t just find a piece of code on the internet and not even bother to copy/paste it in the question and ask people to help you. That is not how “help me” works.

Comment: Add a list variable to the class instance. When its code prints out a path, you know that there is a valid path in the `path` variable it's printing. So add that to your list data member. After it's done printing all the paths, the class instance should have a full list of paths. Make another method or property for the class that returns the list of paths.